# gitlab: protect develop and main branch of new projects by default

Tags: gitlab

we have a self-hosted gitlab server,
I want to protect develop and main branches of all new projects,
additionally I want to protect all existing projects develop branches at once.

Is there a simple way to do that?

I searched the internet for a solution, but found nothing.